# FindRoot of Derivative

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I want to write a function that takes the derivative of `f` wrt `y1` and then find the root of this derivative when `y1` equals `y2`. The function `f` contains several integrals, `y1`, `y2` and `x` also appear as limits of the integrals. Eventually I would like to be able to vary `x` and see how the root changes.

Below is the closest I've gotten, but doesn't work.

```
fd[x_?NumericQ, y1_?NumericQ, y2_?NumericQ] := D[f[x, y1, y2], y1]
fr[x_?NumericQ, y10_?NumericQ] := 
 y1 /. FindRoot[fd[x, y1, y1]==0, {y1, y10}]
```

Am I missing a HoldAll condition for `y2` in `fd`?

Comment: I think you are missing two things. 1. That `FindRoot` works with equations. So, you have to add `Equal` to your code. 2. That `FindRoot` is a completely numerical procedure. Therefore, all your parameters must be assigned to some number. Are you going to assign `x` to something?

Comment: Thanks, I added that `fd` should be equal to 0. And yes, `x` will be assigned a number to evaluate `fr`.

Comment: `D[f[x, y1, y2], y1]` won't work if `y1` is a number. Search the site; there are many solutions presented.  Depending on `f`, `fd[x_?NumericQ, y1_?NumericQ, y2_?NumericQ] = D[f[x, y1, y2], y1]` might work.  So might `fd[x_?NumericQ, y1_?NumericQ, y2_?NumericQ] := Derivative[0,1,0][f][x, y1, y2]`, but it's probably better to compute the derivative once and use the result (again, depends on `f`).

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Note that `FindRoot[x^2 - 2, {x, 1}]` works without an explicit `Equal`. (See the first paradigm in the docs for `FindRoot`.)